# How(procedure) to run automated script(using sikuli) for/on ANDROID devices

Tags: jython

I have written automation script using sikuli for a mobile application in ANDROID emulator. Can u pls tell me the procedure how to write or run in ANDROID device.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You have 2 options : 
1. Launch emulator and then create script that will interact with this emulator
2. Take Android device, connect to it via VNC and then create script that will interact with VNC screen, which will emulate actions on the real device. 
There's more info about that in the net - you can look for Siculi Android, or read about Eggplant - they explain very well how to connect to Android device via VNC.